# Modulo product when the divisor is greater than both large factors

Tags: c++, multiplication, modulo

In my C++ code I have three `uint64_t`variables:

```
uint64_t a =  7940678747;
uint64_t b = 59182917008;
uint64_t c = 73624982323;
```

I need to find `(a * b) % c`. If I directly multiply `a` and `b`, it will cause overflow. However, I can't apply the formula `(a * b) % c = ((a % c) * (b % c)) % c`, because `c > a, c > b` and, consequently, `a % c = a`, `a % c = b` and I will end up multiplying `a` and `b` again, which again will result in overflow.

How can I compute `(a * b) % c` for these values (and such cases in general) of the variables without overflow?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to define `x = 2^32 = 4.29... 10^9`
and then to represent `a` and `b` as:

```
a = ka * x + a1 with ka, a1 < x
b = kb * x + b1 with kb, b1 < x
```

Then

```
a*b = (ka * x + a1) * (kb * x + b1) = ((ka * kb) * x) * x 
      + x * (b1 * ka) + x * (a1 * kb) + a1 * b1
```

All these operations can be performed without the need of a larger type, assuming that all the operations are performed in Z/cZ, i.e. assuming that `% c` operation is performed after each operation (* or +)

Comment: Hm, looks interesting. What are ka, kb, a1, b2? How can I compute them?

Comment: `ka = a / 2^32` and `a1 = a - 2^32 * ka` etc. Note that multiplications and divisions here can be performed with binary shifts. Binary masks can also be used

Answer (score 1):

There are more elegant solutions than this, but an easy one would be looking into a library that deals with larger numbers.  It will handle numbers that are too large for the largest of normal types for you.  Check this one out: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: Sound Unfortunately I can't do it as my code is part of some online judge problem, where I can use only STL and can't include 3rd-party libraries.

Comment: Maybe look into the source code and see how you might be able to implement the necessary functionality?

Comment: *Sound Unfortunately I can't do it as my code is part of some online judge problem* -- Did you [try](https://ideone.com/4bWXcI)?  If these online judge servers have an include to boost, just as ideone does, then this can work.  Also, if you really can't use this library, then maybe the question you're trying to answer on the online judge site is not a suitable one for C++, since C++ has no built-in "big number" library, like, for example, Java.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just did - no joy, they don't have boost.  *maybe the question you're trying to answer on the online judge site is not a suitable one for C++, since C++ has no built-in "big number"* But the statistics shows that there have been solutions written in C++. The problem itself is to find (a ^ b) % c, the problem is that 1 <= a, b, c <= 10^18.

Comment: @alekscooper: `(a ^ b) % c`? Is that a typo? I thought it was `(a * b) % c`.

Comment: @FredLarson No. The initial problem was (a ^ b) % c, 1 <= a, b, c <= 10^18, but I read about a possible solution on KhanAcademy and coded it. Unfortunately, it has a bottleneck, which I posted as a problem here on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class or struct to deal with numbers in parts.

Example PsuedoCode

```
// operation enum to know how to construct a large number
enum operation {
    case add;
    case sub;
    case mult;
    case divide;
}
class bigNumber {
    //the two parts of the number
    int partA;
    int partB;

    bigNumber(int numA, int numB, operation op) {
        if(op == operation.mult) {
            // place each digit of numA into an integer array
            // palce each digit of numB into an integer array
            // Iteratively place the first half of digits into the partA member
            // Iteratively place the second half of digits into the partB member
        } else if //cases for construction from other operations
    }

    // Create operator functions so you can perform arithmetic with this class
}

uint64_t a =  7940678747;
uint64_t b = 59182917008;
uint64_t c = 73624982323;  

bigNumber bigNum = bigNumber(a, b, .mult);
uint64_t result = bigNum % c;
print(result);
```

Keep in mind that you may want to make result of type bigNumber if the value of c is very small.  Basically this was just sort of an outline, make sure if you use a type that it won't overflow.